# atoi() is not converting properly

Tags: atoi

I was trying to call atoi on the strings `509951644` and `4099516441`. The first one got converted without any problem. The second one is giving me the decimal value 2,147,483,647 (0x7FFFFFFF). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Your second integer is creating an overflow. The maximum 32-bit signed integer is 2147483647.

It's generally not recommended to use `atoi` anyway; use `strtol` instead, which actually tells you if your value is out of range. (The behavior of `atoi` is *undefined* when the input is out of range. Yours seems to be simply spitting out the maximum `int` value)

You could also check if your compiler has something like a `atoi64` function, which would let you work with 64-bit values.

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is the maximum integer value in C (signed). It is giving the max that it can... the original is too large to convert to signed int. I suggest looking up how to convert into an unsigned int.